# JavaScript variable scoping - persisting state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, persistence, scope

I have the following setup, and I need to know how to persist state.

1.) An external web page uses ajax to load and display a .jsp file, which contains javascript.
2.) Once this rendering is complete, javascript in the .jsp file must be called to perform an action based on the results that occurred during rendering. Specifically, the document does action on $(document).ready, and those actions dictate what must be done on later function calls.

The question I have is this: How do I persist the data and state created when the page is loaded? I tried something like this:

External:
ajax to test.jsp

Internal test.jsp

```
var saveMe = {};

function getsCalled()  
{  
    saveMe = {'a':function(){return false;}};  
}  

function needsData()  
{  
    //???  
}
```

Later...
External:

```
needsData();
```

Nothing I seem to attempt is working. What would be the best way to persist state in this situation?

Comment: `needsData` will have access to the `saveMe` variable in your example. What does "Nothing [...] is working" mean?

Comment: No attempt to save data was working. needsData DOES NOT have access to saveMe.

in getsCalled(), I set needsData.saveMe = {} to remedy this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems that you are loading the needsData function, after the page had loaded, but you aren't doing anything to tell whatever External is, that there is a method there. You need a global variable in external, and then add needsData to it using the prototype keyword.
e.g. myGlobalVar.prototype.needsData = function(){//???}

Comment: @iftrue: Can you please give us a more elaborate example? In your code example, both `getsCalled` and `needsData` can get and set the `saveMe` variable. See: http://jsbin.com/udufe/edit Click **Output** tab to run the JavaScript code.

Comment: index.jsp: Using ajax, load page.jsp into a div. During the loading of page.jsp, getsCalled() is called. Once loading is complete, call needsData(). needsData cannot see saveMe (this data seems to have been lost), but it can see variables set on the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the variable a member of the function object worked swimmingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know about scoping read [this](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html). It might help you to work out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring saveMe outside of the $(document).ready? Then you should be able to change the value from inside the $(document).ready as well as from the external script. I'm not sure how the scoping works for javascript variables from an ajax call though, so I'm not sure if this would actually work.